# Is there any way to get around 404 on Image.network?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm stuck with this for about 3 hours, and after a lot of research still can't do it.

```
                  FadeInImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(
                        "http://url.test/content/dam/images/aaf/products/_codepageff/${name}.png"),
                    height: 20,
                    placeholder: const AssetImage('assets/wait.png'),
                    imageErrorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                      return Image.asset('assets/ups.png',
                          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth);
                    },
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  ),
```

I've tried A lot of codes, and still without no success on 404. Is there a known error or am I missing anything?
Also I'm building this inside a StatelessWidget class.

Comment: your using a  `NetworkImage` but that looks for an image from _online_. Use `Image.Asset` instead. Or, if that _is_ an image, can you share the link?

Comment: The networkImage had full URL, sorry, i Just hid it.

Comment: the error is probably within `$name`. Does the image load if you  open it directly in you're browser?

Comment: It deppends, some does and some don't, that's why I wanted to add something to show an error, or don't show nothing if url is not valid

Comment: Works for me. Is 'assets/ups.png' declared in assets?

Comment: @user18309290 yes

Answer (score 0):

Give absolute url for `NetworkImage`. 404 means that the image is not found from that url.

Comment: The networkImage had full URL, sorry, i Just hid it.